# How to use Slide effect with jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code so far but not sure how I can use jquery slide effect on an image I'm loading in a `<div>`.

.js I have loaded so far

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryui.js"></script>
```

The HTML code is

```
<div align="center"><img src="images/personal_photo.png" width="900" height="850" alt="Awesome effects"></div>
```

Note: Since I dont know how to apply the jquery-ui effects I have not done anything with the code.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to slide or how, maybe with a link to a demo page?  You might be able to accomplish it with a simple `$.animation`

Comment: I want to do "Slide" effect from the dropdown on this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: Here is my sample code http://pastebin.com/c82DSUzK

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$("img").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
});
```

From
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Comment: Hi. I added that but doesn't seem like it works. Do I need to enter anything in the <div>?  http://pastebin.com/c82DSUzK

Comment: You know what I think I was asking something totally wrong. Is it possible to show that image with that animation?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to show the object and you want the slide *towards the left*, then you have to reverse the direction of the slide.

something like the following:

```
$("img").click(function () {
    $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000); 
});
```